# BeautifulSoup not seeing nobr tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a page with beautifulsoup of the following format

```
<tr class="bgWhite">
<td align="center" width="50"><nobr>A</nobr></td>
<td align="center"> 0</td>
<td align="left" width="*"> 1</td>
<td align="center"> 2</td>
<td align="center"> 3</td>
<td align="center"> 4</td>
<td align="center"><nobr> 23-Apr-13 </nobr></td>
</tr>
```

When I call `col[5].string` or for that manner any index between 1-5, it works fine. However nobr tags seem to cause a problem and return None value when I try do `col[6].string`

I search throught the table with

```
for r_index,row in enumerate(table.findAll('tr')):
    col = row.findAll('td')
```

Idea how to get that data?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, depending on the version of BeautifulSoup:

BeautifulSoup 4, use the `.stripped_strings` attribute to find all text elements that are not empty:

```
print ' '.join(col[6].stripped_strings)
```

In BeautifulSoup 3, you need to search for all contained text instead:

```
print ' '.join(el.strip() for col[6].findAll(text=True) if el.strip())
```

Comment: `col[6].string` shouldn't return `None` with BeautifulSoup 4.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I've seen it return None just fine in BS4. :-) Although right now I cannot seem to reproduce that, I probably got confused with 3.

Comment: I have 3, why does it do that anyways? And el.strip?

Comment: @rodling: The `.strip()` calls remove extra whitespace around the text. The `tr` tag contains *another* tag *first*, and the rest of he text is then considered the 'tail' of that tag.